# Isekai manga where the main character agrees with the villain he just helped to capture

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I only read the 1st few chapters.

The main character was isekaied to another world and was arrested by knights. Their commander was a lady, and apparently the main character passed by a bandits' hideout or something like that before being arrested.

The main character then proceeds to help the knights capture the bandits but the bandits are afraid of their leader because he uses necromancy and can bring them back from the dead if they disobey him.

In the end, they all go to the bandits' hideout to arrest the bandits and the bandit leader is captured. The bandit leader then says that the main character and he have really similar personalities, after which he kills himself. The lady knight remarks that main character isn't like the bandit leader at all, but the main character internally agrees that he actually has a twisted personality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the artwork (how characters were drawn/coloured) or any character or place names?

Comment: A correct answer can be accepted by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is 
[It’s Sudden, but I Came to Another World! But I Hope to Live Safely](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/its-sudden-but-i-came-to-another-world-but-i-hope-to-live-safely/) aka "Isekai demo Bunan ni Ikitai Shoukougun".

The relevant part of the synopsis that mentions a female knight, bandits and being arrested:

> That man stood alone in a mountain full of plants and creatures that he never knew nor saw before. He goes down the mountain by avoiding encounters with a big slime (and bandits), and is caught as a suspicious person in the castle he reaches. In interrogation the female knight Ilias met at the imprisoned place, when talking about the bandits seen in the mountain, Illias, who was stuck in the search for said bandits, hurriedly strikes the bandits.

I didn't read the chapters to confirm whether the bandit leader is a necromancer, but
I found this through a similar identification question on [reddit r/isekai](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/i8hrl4/i_need_help_finding_the_name_of_an_isekai_manga/) which mentions the bandit leader saying he would have been great friends with the mc. The OP there confirmed the series and given everything else matches, I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: 100% correct! Thanks for helping me find it again!